# VB.net OLE DB error

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I am getting this error on the `excecuteNonQuery` line:

> Characters found after end of SQL statement.

My code:

```
deleteObj.CommandText = "UPDATE STUDENTS SET std_name = @name where std_id = @id; UPDATE BALANCE SET Amount= @amount where std_id=@id"

deleteObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtboxName.Text)
deleteObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
deleteObj.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", txtboxBalance.Text)

objConnection.Open()
deleteObj.ExecuteNonQuery()
objConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Is @amount really a string?  I hope not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd reconsider your use of data types, but the answer to your question is that you probably need another semi-colon on the end of your second update statement.

if your using oledb, check the provider you are using accepts named parameters AND that it'll allow you to use multiple queries in one command.

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this

```
deleteObj.CommandText = "UPDATE STUDENTS SET [std_name] = @name where std_id = @id; UPDATE BALANCE SET [Amount]= @amount where std_id=@ id"
```

for example

```
use [Fielddname] :D
```